# Remove keyboard shortcut

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts

I have recently installed tinywall...a lw firewall...it is nice but the firewall have assigned the key combination ctrl+shift+p to open a window of its own, the problem is, the same key combination was supposed to be used for another important task in another program I was using (vs code) , but now it is not working because of the firewall...how can i stop the key combination from opening the firewall without uninstalling it?

Answer (score 7):

Click the the tray icon
Manage -> General -> uncheck enable global hotkeys

Comment: Made my day!!!!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I found the 'uncheck enable global hotkeys' would keep getting re-enabled after disabling it and the 'ctrl-shift-p' behaviour persisted. However, I was able to resolve this by uninstalling tinywall 3.3.1 and reinstalling tinywall 3.3.1 (same version).

After the uninstallation and reinstallation process, 'uncheck enable global hotkeys' was effective and I can also access the vscode <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> shortcut I also wanted.